Can you do an Aveira when someone is taking away all of your money, and what do poskim say on the matter
The Pasuk says that we should live by the Mitzvos, which teaches us that we can do an Aveira to save our, or someone else's life. The Midrash says that people who have nothing are like dead people, so maybe you would be able to do an aveira if someone is robbing you of all your money if you do not do it.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

I don’t think we interpret that midrash literally. We don’t say that people who have no money aren’t obligated in mitzvot anymore because they’re dead. So presumably here it wouldn’t be a justification to do the aveira

Can a pauper kill someone and get away with it? There is no such thing

@CuriousYid Nedarim 64b

The halacha is one must give up all his money not to do an aveirah. (Obviously this assumes no other workaround or option.)
As a general rule, when we say one thing is "like" another thing, that means there is a comparison in at least one aspect, nothing more. If the two things were identical, they would be the same, not merely "alike".

+1 as correct - can you quote the source for completeness?
